# How can I display another form in a z3c.form button handler?

Tags: forms, plone, z3c.form

I have a form with a single text field.

On submit I would like to display another form.

I can use RESPONSE.redirect() and pass it in the query string but I would rather not.

I don't want to use a SESSION variable.

I would like to display a second form which can read this value from the request variable.

I have looked at collective.z3cform.wizard but it is not obvious how to do this.

Trying to call the view() from the button handler does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

collective.singing has a non-session based wizard which uses hidden fields to store results of intermediate steps.

Answer (score 1):

I fall in the same lack of functionality.

For what I know, z3c.form does not support this kind of traversing.

You may remember that this functionality worked well with CMFFormController.
Actually to do this, cmfformcontroller used session machinery.

So, you don't want to use session but that's the way. At least I do so, and I'm happy.

In this way there's no need of a wrapping tool like z3c.form.wizard.

hth,
alessandro.

Comment: why not? you have to use sticky session in your load balancer.

Comment: Feels like a wrong approach of solving a problem at a different place than where it happens. Also stickiness can impact performance negatively.